# Combining two different PredicateBuilders with Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions, predicatebuilder, linq-extensions

I am having a predicate builder and it is working fine

```
 var filter = sortKeys.Aggregate(filter, (currentFilter, sortkey) => currentFilter.Or(
                            x => x.Appointments.Any(y => y.RowStatus == Constants.CurrentRowStatus )));
```

I am now trying to split the conditions which is inside the appointment into another predicate builder so that I can add conditions on the go and reuse the function.

I had tried creating an expression and then using it in the main predicate builder but it is failing

```
private static Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> TmpApt(string status)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Appointment>();

        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.RowStatus == status);

        return predicate;
    }
```

Changed main predicate to use the above expression

```
var filter = sortKeys.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.True<Person>(), (current, s) =>
                                current.Or(x => x.Appointments.Any(TmpApt(s))));
```

It showing an error that

> Argument type '`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Appointment,bool>>`' is
>       not assignable to parameter type `System.Func<Appointment,bool>`

I had even tried LinqKit extension method like Expand but could find a solution.

had also tried [Reusable predicate expressions in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326321/reusable-predicate-expressions-in-linq-to-entities-queries), then it is not showing any errors while compiling but when on the application side, it is showing

> Unsupported overload used for query operator '`Any`'.

Can anyone please help me how to resolve the error or suggest an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQKit to invoke the expression that you have at the location that you want to be using it:

```
var predicate = TmpApt();
var filter = sortKeys.Aggregate(PredicateBuilder.False<Person>(),
    (current, s) => current.Or(x =>
        x.Appointments.Any(appointment => predicate.Invoke(appointment))))
        .Expand();
```

Note that you'll need to pull `TmpApt` out into a variable for LINQKit to successfully evaluate it, due to a bug in its implementation.

Also note that you'll want to initialize the aggregate operation to `False`, because `True` OR-ed with anything is `true`.

Also note that you can simplify the implementation of `TmpApt` to just the following:

```
private static Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> TmpApt()
{
    return p => p.RowStatus == Constants.CurrentRowStatus;
}
```

There's no need to use a predicate builder to `Or` it with `False` here.

Comment: Thanks very much... Your solution is working great but I am having a new problem now.. I want to pass parameters into TmpApt(). The parameter values are coming from "s" (which is in the aggregrate). I am not sure how to pass when we declare it as a variable and then invoking it. Is there any workaround for this. I will update the main question also. I am sorry it was my mistake. T. make the question easy I had removed the variable of the method. Thanks very much for your help and for you time.

Comment: @Rocky Well The simplest option would be to refactor the invocation of `TmpApt` to the `Aggregate` lambda.  It can't be within the lambda that is compiled to an expression, unless you want to first fix the bug in LINQKit, which is certainly possible, but not simple.